# Get PDB ID + Chain ID from Uniprot ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb

I have a list of Uniprot IDs and need to know the PDB IDs plus the Chain IDs.
With the code given on the Uniprot website I can get the PDB IDs but not the Chain Information.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/'

params = {
'from': 'ACC+ID',
'to': 'PDB_ID',
'format': 'tab',
'query': UniProtIDs
}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with open('UniProt_PDB_IDs.txt', 'a') as f:
   with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as q:
      response = q.read()
      f.write(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

so this code gets me this:

```
From    To
A0A075B6N1  5HHM
A0A075B6N1  5HHO
A0A075B6N1  5NQK
A0A075B6T6  1AO7
A0A075B6T6  4ZDH
```

for the Protein A0A075B6N1 with PDB ID 5HHM the Chains are E and J so i need a way to also retrieve the chains to get something like that:

```
A0A075B6N1  5HHM_E 
A0A075B6N1  5HHM_J
A0A075B6N1  5HHo_E
A0A075B6N1  5NQK_B
```

It doesen't has to be in this format, later I convert it into a dictionary with the UniProt IDs as keys and the PDB IDs as values.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A tool called localpdb was just recently released that might does exactly what you want: https://labstructbioinf.github.io/localpdb/.

Another way would be to split the structures by segments, which can be easily done with MDanalysis universe objects (https://www.mdanalysis.org). Assuming you have a list of PDB IDs:

```
#fetch structures
universe_objects = []
for pdb_id in pdb_ids:
    mmtf_object = mda.fetch_mmtf(pdb_id)
    universe_objects.append(mmtf_object)

#get rid of water and ligands and split structures into chains
universe_chains = []
for universe_object in universe_objects:
    universe_chain = universe_object.select_atoms('protein').split('segment')
    universe_chains.append(universe_chain)
    
#flatten nested list
universe_chain_list = [item for sublist in universe_chains for item in sublist]
```

Of course there is other tools you can do this with. E.g. via the ProDy Hierview function!

Hope that helps.